# URL request, python to R translation please

Tags: r

I'm trying to request some data via the mt gox API (mtgox.com) and theres some example code in python that I'd like to basically copy into R.

```
import hmac, base64, hashlib, urllib2
base = 'https://data.mtgox.com/api/2/'

def makereq(key, secret, path, data):
hash_data = path + chr(0) + data
secret = base64.b64decode(secret)
sha512 = hashlib.sha512
hmac = str(hmac.new(secret, hash_data, sha512))

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'My-First-Trade-Bot',
    'Rest-Key': key,
    'Rest-Sign': base64.b64encode(hmac),
    'Accept-encoding': 'GZIP',
}

return urllib2.Request(base + path, data, header)
```

I have some R code already

```
install.packages("base64")
install.packages("caTools")
install.packages("digest")
install.packages("RCurl")
library(RCurl)
library(caTools)
library(base64)
base<- "https://data.mtgox.com/api/2"
path<- "BTCUSD/money/ticker"
APIkey<-"******" #this is private but its a long hex number
secretAPIkey<-"*****" #this too, but this is in base64


makeReq<-function(key, secret, path, post_data)
{
  browser()
  message <- paste(path,  NULL, post_data)
  secret<-base64decode(secret,"character")
  theHmac <-hmac(secret,message,"sha512")
  header <- 
  {
    c(
    User.Agent = "My Bot",
    Rest.Key = key,
    Rest.Sign = base64encode(theHmac),
    Acccept.encoding = "GZIP"
    )
  }
  return (getURL(paste(base,path), post_data, header) )
}
```

I don't know how to get the "header" thing to work though, and I might be using getURL() incorrectly.
If you want to see the whole problem, the instructions are here https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/overview, scroll down to the first block of code.

but I'm probably just making some elementary mistake with R header syntax...

Comment: anyone? feedback if this is a bad question...?

Comment: try this (untested): `getURL(paste(base,path), post_data, httpheader=header)`

Comment: The default for paste is `sep = " "`. So `paste(base,path)` is making a string with a space in it.

Comment: Ferdinand I tried yours (except with the sep="") and got
        Error in curlOptions(URL = url, writefunction = writeFun, ...,         .opts = .opts) : 
          unnamed curl option(s): nonce= 136528265105565

Comment: @hedgedandlevered, the problem is that the argument `post_data` is being handled by the `...` formal argument in `getURL`. You need to specify a name for it, but I don't know what name is supposed to be used. Try `?getURL`...

Comment: Is there any reason you have to implement this in R? If you have it already implemented in python, it might be worth looking into the rpy2 library for the R component, which will allow you to call R commands from within python.

Answer (score 0):

try to use postForm (from RCurl) instead of getURL:

```
postForm(paste(base,path),
  .opts = list(postfields = post_data,
              useragent   = 'R',
              httpheader  = c('Rest-Key'  = key,
                              'Rest-Sign' = base64encode(theHmac)),
              timeout = 4,
              ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
         )
```